# I want my service and broadcast receiver to run even if app is cleared from app list or forced stop

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I want my service and broadcast receiver to run in background even if app is closed or force stopped.

My receiver is detecting screen on response and doing the task.
Its working fine when app is open and when app is in app list but not closed.
When i clear the app from app list, it is not detecting the screen on response.
I have tried many ways but couldn't succeed. Help me out.

**Manifest file :-**

```
<receiver
        android:name=".broadcastReceiver.MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".service.MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:stopWithTask="false">

    </service>
```

**MyService class :-**

```
private var myReceiver:MyReceiver?=null

private var defaultUEH:Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler?=null
private var uncaughtExceptionHandler = object:Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler{

    override fun uncaughtException(thread: Thread?, ex: Throwable?) {

        Log.d("Exception found","Uncaught exception start!")
        ex!!.printStackTrace()

        unregisterReceiver(myReceiver)

        var intent = Intent(applicationContext, MyService::class.java)
        intent.setPackage(packageName)
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(applicationContext,1,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
        var alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+1000,pendingIntent)
        System.exit(2)

    }

}

override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
   return null
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    var intentFilter = IntentFilter("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF")
    intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON")

    myReceiver = MyReceiver()
    registerReceiver(myReceiver , intentFilter)

    return START_STICKY
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    Log.d("Service" , "onCreate fun")
}

override fun onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy()

    Log.d("Service" , "onDestroy fun")
}

override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {

    unregisterReceiver(myReceiver)

    var intent = Intent(applicationContext, MyService::class.java)
    intent.setPackage(packageName)
    var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,1,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
    var alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+1000,pendingIntent)
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)

}
```

**MyReceiver class:-**

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

    Log.d("Where ","Broadcast")
    if (intent!!.action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){

        var dashboardActivity = DashboardActivity.instance
        var isSosEnabled = dashboardActivity!!.getSos()

        if (isSosEnabled){
            Log.d("Service Sos Enabled","True")
        }else{
            Log.d("Service Sos Enabled", "False")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use a service
In main app start/stop the service**

```
Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
context.startService(service);
...
Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
context.stopService(service);
```

**service**

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
 private static BroadcastReceiver m_ScreenOffReceiver;

 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
 {
  return null;
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate()
 {
  registerScreenOffReceiver();
 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy()
 {
  unregisterReceiver(m_ScreenOffReceiver);
  m_ScreenOffReceiver = null;
 }

 private void registerScreenOffReceiver()
 {
  m_ScreenOffReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
  {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
   {
     Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_SCREEN_OFF");
     // do something, e.g. send Intent to main app
   }
  };
  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
  registerReceiver(m_ScreenOffReceiver, filter);
 }
}
```

Comment: It is tested on my device and working fine dont know about you. You can have look on this [uselink] https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android

Comment: Ok sometimes it happens

Comment: Happy to help. Consider up voting as well for the benefit of people who stumble upon this question.